# NLog, .net core: How to get access to a specific logger in my service through dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, nlog

Software versions:

- .NET Core v5.0
- NLog v4.7.6
- Microsoft Extensions Logging v5
- VisualStudio2019

I'm using NLog along with Microsoft logging extensions in my .net core console application.

The application contains multiple services that run in background as hosted services.

Each service has access to its typed logger that is set in its constructor through the usual dependency injection. But I also need to add access to a special email logger that will send out an email on critical exceptions. Is there any other way to get a special logger injected into my serivce instead of creating it from "NLog.LogManager.GetLogger()" in every service?

```
    public class TestService: IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestService> _logger;
        private readonly ILogger _emailOnFatalError;

        public TestService(ILogger<TestService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            //_emailOnFatalError = (ILogger) NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("emailOnFatalError");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I remember, you can route different log levels to different logger source within NLog, so just configure to send Fatal log level to email and all others to file. So _logger.LogFatal will be sent to email, _logger.LogInformation - to file

Comment: @IvanKhorin, yes that's possible, but I don't want to send all fatal log messages to email, only a small subset of those that require immediate attention from the dev team.

Comment: Ok, use filters with "when" statement like `<when condition="contains('${message}','URGENT!!!:')" action="Ignore" />` and just use pattern for very urgent messages to be emailed. Second Idea is to invoke NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("emailOnFatalError"); in the configuration section and inject the result as Singleton for example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having ILogger as constructor-parameter, then use [ILoggerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory):

```
public class TestService: IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ILogger _emailOnFatalError;

    public TestService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType().ToString());
        _emailOnFatalError = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("emailOnFatalError");
    }
}
```

Alternative consider adding an event-property like this:

```
_logger.LogError("Something awful - {EmailAlert}", "Important");
```

Then you can use [NLog filtering](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages) to only send log-events that contains `${event-property:EmailAlert}`:

```
<logger name="*" writeTo="emailOnFatalError" minLevel="Error">
   <filters defaultAction="Log">
      <when condition="'${event-property:EmailAlert}' == ''" action="Ignore" />
   </filters>
 </logger>
```